# How Can I Pass CSV Values to an API Field?

Tags: node.js, api, facebook-graph-api, request

I'm using the following node request for the New York Times Article Search API, but I'm having trouble with passing multiple values to the 'fl' field, which asks for a

> "Comma-delimited list of fields."

My request looks like this:

```
let request = require('request');
var jsonfile = require('jsonfile')
var obj;

request.get({
    url: "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json",
    qs: {
        'api-key': "d3a29a2e27b04abd8f15260942e362d9",
        'q': "title ix",
        'begin_date': "19720101",
        'fl': "headline",
        'hl': "true"
    },
}, (err, response, body) => {
    body = JSON.parse(body);
    jsonfile.writeFile('data.json', body, (err) => console.error(err))
});
```

I've tried sending the 'fl' field an array, a JSON object, etc but nothing seems to work. How I can pass the fl field both "headline" and "pub_date"?

Edit: My error message looks like this

> {   "status": "ERROR",   "copyright": "Copyright (c) 2013 The New York
>   Times Company.  All Rights Reserved.",   "errors": [
>       "Parameter  value failed to match validation rule:: <>"
>   ],   "results": [] }

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it simply be:

`fl: 'term1,term2,term3',`

That's comma separated values associated to a single query string parameter. Could you provide additional documentation if that doesn't work.